# Parse JSON using Swift / SwiftyJSON

Tags: json, swift, swift2

I've followed several tutorials on this, and as far as I can tell what I'm doing should be working.  I have the following json response from an api call

```
{
    "Id": "1",
    "Name": "Test User",
    "Email": "test@email.com",
    "ProfileImage": null,
    "IsAdmin": true,
    "TakesJobs": false,
    "IsLocationUser": false,
    "IsCompanyAdmin": true,
    "LocationUsers": [],
    "CompanyUsers": [{
        "CompanyName": "Test Company",
        "Id": 6,
        "CompanyId": 5,
        "UserId": "1",
        "Admin": true,
        "TakesJobs": false,
        "UserName": null,
        "UserEmail": null,
        "AssignedJobs": null
    }]
}
```

Essentially I just want to check if the Id value is blank or not.  Here is the code I'm using

The res return type is JSON

```
ApiConnector.sharedInstance.login(emailText.text!, password: passwordText.text!) { (res) in
    if let id = res["Id"] as? String {
        if id != "" {

        }
        else
        {

        }

    }
}
```

I get a warning that says Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type 'String' always fails.

What do I need to change to see the value of Id?

This is the code from the ApiConnector class

```
func login(username: String, password: String, onCompletion: (JSON) -> Void) {
    let route = baseURL + "auth?Email=" + username + "&Password=" + password
    makeHTTPPostRequest(route, body: ["Email":username, "Password": password], onCompletion: { json, err in
        onCompletion(json as JSON)
        })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
ApiConnector.sharedInstance.login(emailText.text!, password: passwordText.text!) { (res) in
    if let id = res["Id"].string {
      // Do something.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What library are you using for handle json? If swift json you can do something like

```
res["id"]?.string
```

If you don't say anything on the type of "res" we can't answer you.

Comment: Sorry, totally spaced that.  I edited the title to reflect it.  I'm using SwiftyJSON

Comment: The res return type is JSON.  I updated my question with that information as well.